# Extract data from API website link using AXIOS (JSON Map Data)

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I have the following code:

```
let getResponse = async () => {
  let checkemoji = await axios.get(`https://somewebsite.com/misc/EmojiMap.json`)
  let response = checkemoji.data
  return response
}
let responsevalue = await getResponse()
let findemoji = responsevalue.emojiDefinitions.surrogates
console.log(findemoji)
```

`checkemoji.data.emojiDefinitions` returns as `undefined`.

Here Is the what I get from the API data:

```
{
  "version": "1574367168751",
  "versionTimestamp": "2019-11-21T20:12:48.7512821+00:00",
  "emojiDefinitions": [
    {
      "primaryName": "grinning",
      "primaryNameWithColons": ":grinning:",
      "names": [
        "grinning"
      ],
      "namesWithColons": [
        ":grinning:"
      ],
      "surrogates": "",
      "utf32codepoints": [
        128512
      ],
      "assetFileName": "7c010dc6da25c012643ea22c1f002bb4.svg",
      "assetUrl": "https://discordapp.com/assets/7c010dc6da25c012643ea22c1f002bb4.svg"
    },
    // etc...
  ]
}
```

I am trying to extract only the ''surrogates'' data, based on an emoji I give it.

For example: "️" .

I tried using:

```
 let findemoji = responsevalue.find(post => post.emojiDefinitions.surrogates === myemoji) // myemoji = ️
```

But it returns `find is not a function`.

Comment: `find` works on array, seems like `responsevalue` isn't an array. Hence its throwing `find is not a function` error. Try logging the value and share the response please

Comment: Gave you the `.data` response in my question. `.data.emojiDefinitions returns undefined`, that being my main issue. (edited the question so you can understand it better)

Answer (score 1):

responsevalue  is only JSON ，you can use JSON. parse(responsevalue) and return object ,so you can't use find that be long to array

Comment: Interesting idea, bug I get this error: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0` and this is my code: `let findemoji = JSON.parse(responsevalue)`, `let myemoji = findemoji.emojiDefinitions.surrogate`, `console.log(myemoji)`. At the syntax error, the unexpected token is double spaces `(  )`. By the way, there are multiple values in emojiDefinitions with multiple values of surrogates, I just need to find the one I need.

Answer (score 0):

Try console.log(response) in your getResponse function. If it prints undefined then that means that you are not getting response to your webpage. If you are getting response your checkemoji.data.emojiDefinitions is an array so your find should be:

```
let findemoji = responsevalue.emojiDefinitions.find(post => post.surrogates === myemoji)
```

Comment: Yes I get a response like I've posted in my question. My issue is that I get emojiDefinitions returned as `UNDEFINED` which I don't know how to fix. (tried your find too, got `TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined`)

Comment: and same structure response is printed out when you console.log(responsevalue ) after let responsevalue = await getResponse()?

Comment: yes. the function is correct (the .data is working). Tried making it a non-function and I have the same result.

Comment: could you post how your response looks in devtools? (As screenshoot)

Comment: I'm using NODEJS for a discord bot. Not using DevTools. The response is listed here: https://static.emzi0767.com/misc/discordEmojiMap.json .

Comment: I tried to store your data in different location (https://extendsclass.com/api/json-storage/bin/fbfeeef ) and im getting response perfectly fine. Maybe if you have possibility try to store your data somewhere else (because i think axios cant get response to your javascript from your link).

Comment: the issue is that I get a response.. the exact data I have on website. It just returns undefined. I will try to store the data in a JSON file.

Comment: https://steemit.com/utopian-io/@superoo7/discord-bot-tutorial-making-a-discord-bot-detailed-write-up also this link shows how to create discord bot. Maybe this will help for you to find mistake

Comment: Regarding discord bots, I code discord bots for already 2 years+, pretty sure no mistake there. I only have issues regarding axios.

Answer (score 0):

```
        var myemoji = "";
    async function getResponse(){
        try {
            let response = await axios.get(`EmojiMap.json`)
            return response.data;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }

    getResponse().then( res => {
        let findemoji = res.emojiDefinitions.find(post => post.surrogates === myemoji) // myemoji = ️
        console.log(findemoji)
    });
```

Comment: Same error. Also it's not a json file btw, is a website. 

res.emojIDefinitions returns as undefined. `TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined`

Comment: try to console.log(response); after `let response = await axios.get('EmojiMap.json')`, and after `getResponse().then( res => {` console.log(res);. and see if any data returned

Comment: It returns what's here: https://static.emzi0767.com/misc/discordEmojiMap.json , when I console.log(response). same for console.log(res)